# How to know if the cache is loaded on databricks

Tags: sql, reactjs, caching, databricks, aws-databricks

I'm using Databricks cache with Reactjs in order to improve the performance when the app request something. But, how do I know when the cache is ready? Because when I run the SQL sentence, e.g `CACHE SELECT * FROM table`, doesn't return anything. There is any way to know if the cache is loaded correctly?

Thanks!